# Linux: How to send message to local user logged into X11?

Tags: linux, xorg

Is possible to send a message (popup window or something) to local user logged into X (xdm, fluxbox) from console ? For example: `user1` is logged and using X/fluxbox, `user2` logging into the same box by ssh to console. Now - what `user2` have to do to send message to `user1` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `xmessage` tool lets you do exactly that; present a popup window to users with a text message inside.

Example: user2 logs into a BASH session on the box and issues:

```
export DISPLAY=':0.0'
xmessage "some message here"
```

if you log into a TSCH session, it'd be something like this:

```
setenv DISPLAY ':0.0'
xmessage "some message here'
```

Alternatively, you can send messages to terminal sessions in one of two ways:

Using `wall` (=warn all [users])

From the man page:
Wall displays the contents of file or, by default, its standard input, on
the terminals of all currently logged in users.

If you want to target a specific user, use `write`. Again, man tells us:

The write utility allows you to communicate with other users, by copying lines from your terminal to theirs.

Comment: If a recipient (`user1` in my example) is logged into X11, and haven't opened `xterm` or other terminal - will `wall` work too ? I think that `user1` will not see messages.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the 'xmessage' solution. That will show a small window to the user, irrespective of whether they have a terminal open.

Comment: Incidentally, 'apropos' is a useful utility to know; it searches manual pages for the text you pass to it. Try running 'apropos message' and see what it returns.

Comment: I know `xmessage` but how to run it by `user1` and get this small window opened on `user2`'s screen ? is it even possible ?

Comment: @marioosh I would also like to know how to do that. Did you ever get it figured out?

Comment: `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"`

Answer (score 3):

As a rule, X11 sessions are usually started in a “private” mode, so you require one of two things: either, coöperation from `user2` to allow you to access their screens, or superuser privileges to “break in” to their screens.

**DANGER:** Do keep in mind, once you have access to their screen, you could also do things like capture keystrokes (potentially including passwords) and take screenshots, so this is a big security risk.

In *most* cases it's preferable to instead use a messaging tool or chat program for these things.

Caveats aside:

**Coöperating**

If `user2` wants to allow `user1` to access their screen, then first `user2` must issue a command like:

```
 xhost +si:localuser:user1
```

This could potentially be added to a start-up script of some kind; I don't know Fluxbox, but I assume it has a `rc` or session-start hook.

Once this has been issed, `user1` can then write to `user2`'s display, if they can find it.

If `user2` is aware of this, they can always send it to `user1` in some other way.

**Finding another user's Display**

On a typical workstation, it's unusual to have more than one or two users logged in; in which case, “guessing” that the display you want is 0, 1, or maybe 2 might be a workable solution.

However, for a more complete solution, let's assume that you have a machine where very many users could be signed in, and try to find the one you want.

```
for proc in /proc/[0-9]*/
do
     if [ Xorg = $(< $proc/comm ) ] 2>/dev/null && \
        [ $(id -u user2) -eq $(< $proc/loginuid) ] 2>/dev/null
     then
        for subproc in $(
        do
            echo "user2 display=" $(perl -ne 'if (m,DISPLAY=(.*)\0,) { print $1 }' < $subproc/environ)
        done
     fi
done
```

then, `user1` can finally (using the DISPLAY value obtained above; I've just written `:14.0` here…)

```
DISPLAY=:14.0 xmessage "Hello, user2"
```

**Sending a Notification instead**

In the interests of completeness, the following works on Gnome desktop, at least. I don't know if Fluxbox has a notification widget.

```
 DISPLAY=:14.0 notify-send "Hello, user2"
```

This has a lot more user-friendly options for display, and probably will pop up in a rather friendlier way on the user's screen.

Comment: `for subproc in` what?  I think your script is corrupted here.

Comment: I'd like to use `notify-send` (which is how I ended up here), but using `DISPLAY=:N.n notify-send` only works if I do it as the user I want to send it to -- and if I do it from the GUI, lol (meaning it is totally useless).  Otherwise `notify-send` either does nothing or blocks indefinitely.  *Did you actually test this when you wrote it?*

Comment: It was working with whatever version of Gnome+Fedora were current in 2016, but I haven't rechecked since. I often use `notify-send` from scripts but usually as "myself" … I suppose some `sudo` magic could work if the dbus system is more locked-down now?

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly "off the `wall`" suggestion.

Install `espeak` (or  `espeak-ng`) on the target machine from your ssh execute

```
 espeak "The matrix has you"
```

Espeak is a text to speech engine, and will output to the console's speakers.  If the volume is not set to zero, this will cause the computer to speak to the local user.

Comment: pun intended...

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who could not get `notify-send` to work by setting `DISPLAY` to that of the target user, you can use that or any other command by reading from a pipe that messages can be sent to.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=/home/you/notify-pipe/
fifo=$dir/notifications

if [ ! -e $fifo ]; then 
# The '$dir' path must exist or mkfifo will fail.
    if [ ! -e $dir ]; then 
        mkdir -p $dir
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit $?; fi
    fi
    mkfifo -p $fifo
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit $?; fi
fi

echo $BASHPID > $dir/bash.pid
# All errors etc. from here on logged
exec &>> $dir/log.txt
date

while [ -e $fifo ]; do
    read line < $fifo
    notify-send "$line"
done
```

You can then run this in the background with `setsid -f ./whatever.sh` (or autostart it via your DE).  Other users and system processes can then notify by writing to the FIFO (eg. "echo hello > /home/you/notify-pipe/notifications").  If your home is not publicly readable the pipe can be anywhere.

To stop it you'll have to kill it or delete the pipe. *Beware that a pitfall of this is that if the pipe exists but nothing is reading from it (eg. the script), writing a message (eg. via `echo`) will block until something does read it.*

Comment: Nice! But what it is `bash.pid` used for?

Comment: It seems that `mkfifo` in GNU coreutils 8.32 does not create intermediate path segments, and there is no such `-p` option like `mkdir -p`. So it will fail if `$dir` does not exists.

Comment: Thank you -- probably worth noting. I've added some checks and comments about this.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: The following is based on sending graphical notifications to the user via `notify-send`. This is a slightly modified version of the @goldilocks answer.

- It takes care of creating any intermediate directory for the fifo file.
- It will work posting all missed notifications written to the queue when the reading script is stopped (I don't know why but in the original one I was only getting one notification when the read side was stopped).

  This should allow any user with write permissions to the destination user's queue to send a notification disregarding the recipient is logged or not. You can think in notifications from root/systemd for example. BUT anyway, I don't think this "pending" notifications are persistent, as the sender process needs to be alive for the recipient to receive it. So, if I'm not wrong a reboot or logout (in case of being another user) will make it a dead letter.

File: `~/.config/autostart/start-notification-queue` (make it executable `chmod +x`)

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

QUEUE=$HOME/.cache/notification-queue

# ---

basedir=$(dirname "$QUEUE")

[[ ! -d "$basedir" ]] && mkdir -p "$basedir"
[[ ! -e "$QUEUE" ]]   && mkfifo "$QUEUE"

while [[ -e "$QUEUE" ]]; do
  while read line; do
    notify-send "[Notification queue]" "$line"
  done < "$QUEUE"
done
```

### How to auto start it

You can use Freedesktop (XDG) autostart spec to start the queue listener upon desktop startup. Just place the following file and your desktop environment should start it.

File: `~/.config/autostart/notification-queue.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Start user notification queue
Type=Application
Exec=bash -c '$HOME/.config/autostart/start-notification-queue'
Terminal=false
```